# Converting class to function

Tags: javascript, class, momentjs, feathersjs

I'm making a real time app and want to convert this `class` code to a `function`.

Would the function below be the equivalent? And from what anyone can see, would there be a benefit to keeping it a class as opposed to a function?

```
class IdeaService {
  constructor() {
    this.ideas = [];
  }

  async find() {
    return this.ideas;
  }

  async create(data) {
    const idea = {
      id: this.ideas.length,
      text: data.text,
      tech: data.tech,
      viewer: data.viewer
    };

    idea.time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');

    this.ideas.push(idea);

    return idea;
  }
}
```

**FUNCTION**

```
function ideaService() {

let ideas = [];

 async find() {

  return ideas;

 }

 async create(data) {

 const idea = {

      id:     ideas.length,
      text:   data.text,
      tech:   data.tech,
      viewer: data.viewer

    }

    idea.time = moment().formate('h:mm:ss a');

    ideas.push(idea);

    return idea;

 }

}
```

Comment: "*And from what anyone can see, would there be a benefit to keeping it a class as opposed to a function?*" why do you want to convert the class to a function if you don't know if you need that or not?

Comment: The function version is a syntax error, which you could find out by trying it, so I guess continuing to work would be the advantage of keeping it a class.

Comment: @VLAZ i prefer to avoid having to worry about `this` and the class syntax in general

Comment: @and1 If you want to use objects with methods, you will have to "worry about `this`" (i.e. understand how to use it) no matter what syntax you use.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
let IdeaService = (function() {
    let ideas = [];

    async function find() {
        return ideas;
    }

    async function create(data) {
        const idea = {
            id: ideas.length,
            text: data.text,
            tech: data.tech,
            viewer: data.viewer
        };

        idea.time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
        ideas.push(idea);
        return idea;
    }

    return {
        find,
        create
    }
})();
```

EDIT! If youd like this module to NOT be instantiated upon this file running remove the (); at the end. so the function would be:

```
IdeaService = (function() {
});
```

and to instantiate it would be:

```
let ideaService = IdeaService();
```